# How to add extra charcter in a list of string?

Tags: c#, list

I had a list of strings

```
var li = new List<string>()
{
    "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6",
};
```

I want to concatinate some some character in each word output list will be will be

```
word1#,word2#,word3#,word4#,word5#,word6#
```

Comment: You need output as list or string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing this:

```
li = li.Select(x => x + "#").ToList();
```

If you mean you want to output the string "word1#,word2#,word3#,word4#,word5#,word6#", then, after the above line, do this:

```
var output = String.Join(",", li);
```

Comment: @wudzik - Yes, it will. The first line takes care of that. The `String.Join` happens after the `Select`/`.ToList`.

Comment: This is exactly what OP wants. `+1` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var word = string.Join("#,",li)+"#";
```

It will join your strings separated with `#,`

Comment: But it won't put a "#" at the end though.

Comment: Why isn't SO showing that this question was edited? The `+"#"` code was added after my comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Edits made within 5 minutes of posting aren't shown.

Comment: @keyboardP - Thanks for letting me know. Doesn't that make it hard to reconcile the comments (like in this case)?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yes sometimes but I think people will assume it was edited after the comment unless the poster actually tries to deny it (never seen that happen before :D)

Comment: I said "good point" so everyone will know I've edited my post :)